# How to Give break in line Javascript and specific color for each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to give break for each line and also give color for specific text.

```
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }).setText(
    'Trenza Softwares'
    +
    '1/A New Circular Road (5th Floor) ' +
    'Opposite to Century Arcade Shopping Complex, Moghbazar Wireless ' +
    ' Dhaka-1217 Bangladesh'
);
```

Comment: "I want to give break" ... `\n` is the line break char. Literally using new lines in your editor doesn't change the value of the string. It must be explicit

Answer (score 0):

var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 25}).setHTML(

```
            '<p> <span>Trenza Softwares</span> <br>1/A New Circular Road (5th Floor) <br>Opposite to Century Arcade Shopping Complex, Moghbazar Wireless,<br>Dhaka-1217 Bangladesh</p>'

    
);
```